# Не понимаю, почему не работает ChildNode.before()

Tags: javascript

Здраствуйте! Решился я сделать простенькую програму проверки правильности умножения двух чисел. Некий тест, где в конце бы выводилась информация о количестве сделанных ошибок. В html документе минимум тегов.

**HTML**

```
<body onload="main()">
    <span id="firstSpan">Test1:</span>
    <span id="secondSpan">Test2:</span>
    <form id="mainForm">
        <input type="text" id="text">
    </form>
</body>
```

Все проблемы начинаются в скрипте:

**JS**

```
function main() {
...
            var input = document.getElementById("text");
            var str = document.createElement('span');
            str.innerHTML = numb1 + " x " + numb2 + " =";
            str.before(input); // На сколько я понимаю проблема вот в этой строчке кода. Я что-то делаю не так и она вместо того, чтобы вставляться перед полем input не делает ничего.
...
        }
```

Не понимаю, что я делаю не так, т.к довольно часто у меня бывают ситуации, когда этот метод может упросить мне жизнь, а я не понимаю, как им пользоваться и почему он у меня не работает(

Comment: ну в логе посмотри, что такое `str.before(input)`

Comment: В логе все хорошо: `<span>4 x 8 =</span>` Именно это я пытаюсь вывести на страницу, но не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function main() {
  var input = document.getElementById("text");
  var str = document.createElement('span');
  str.innerHTML = "TEST";//numb1 + " x " + numb2 + " =";
  //str.before(input);
  input.before(str);
}
```

```html
<body onload="main()">
  <span id="firstSpan">Test1:</span>
  <span id="secondSpan">Test2:</span>
  <form id="mainForm">
    <input type="text" id="text">
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Ааа, блин, опять элементарное решение. Я запутался в документации и неправильно понял, как работает метод. Спасибо большое!